# Unexpected reference count for unnamed integer literal

Tags: python

I understand that, in CPython 2.x and 3.x, some integers are singletons:

```
>>> a = 256; a is 256    # or any integer from -5 to 256
True

>>> a = 257; a is 257    # or any other integer outside the magic range
False
```

Accordingly, if I run `sys.getrefcount` on an integer in the range -5 to 256, I find that a lot of my imported packages have referenced that integer:

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
1470
```

I also understand that `sys.getrefcount` returns 1 more than you might expect, because of its *own* reference to the argument:

```
>>> a = 257; sys.getrefcount(a)
2
```

What I don't get is this:

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(257)
3
```

Why 3, not 2?  I could understand that I might have created a temporary variable in my own scope (count 1), and clearly `sys.getrefcount` would add another reference of its own to that (count 2) but where does the third one come from, and why didn't happen in the previous example?   And more importantly: are there other contexts in which this might occur, leading to possible misinterpretation of `sys.getrefcount` outputs?

All of the above are replicable for me on 64-bit Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.1 by Anaconda, running on OSX, and also on a 32-bit Python 2.7.5 distribution running on Windows.   However, on an older Python version (32-bit Python 2.5.4 on Windows), `sys.getrefcount(257)` returns 2 which is (to me) more expected.

Comment: Does it matter? Implementation details may or may not lead to an immutable literal being cached as a constant.

Comment: From the documentation, *Return the reference count of the object. The count returned is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount().*

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: that's just 2 of the 3 references, the OP notes they already managed to count that far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into an implementation detail here. The compiler can often *cache* immutable literal values:

```
>>> import dis
>>> compile("sys.getrefcount(257)", '', 'single').co_consts
(257, None)
>>> dis.dis(compile("sys.getrefcount(257)", '', 'single'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (sys)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (getrefcount)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (257)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 PRINT_EXPR
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

(`'single'` is the mode used by the interactive interpreter).

We see 3 references here; one from the `co_consts` tuple on the code object, one on the stack (from the `LOAD_CONST` instruction), and one for the `sys.getrefcount()` method itself.

Comment: Thanks.  So I presume we can have faith that `sys.getrefcount` won't mysteriously bump the ref count (by *more* than the expected 1) in any other situations (situations which might matter more....)?

Comment: @jez: you can trust `sys.getrefcount()`. You can always [create a debug build of Python](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Misc/SpecialBuilds.txt) that lets you trace reference counting in more detail if you have reason to believe there is a bug somewhere.